# iOS - Any Delegate Method or Notification which automatically call when Bluetooth device disconnected

Tags: ios, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am working on BLE device with iOS. These devices working fine when I search the list of Bluetooth devices in Range and then make a connection with them.

In between sometimes the device is disconnected due to some range or other reasons. Now I want to get some notification which shows the user the message that device is disconnected So he/she can connect it again.

**Is there are any Delegate Method available to check connection or disconnection** or how we can achieve this. Please guide me any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Method from CBCentralManagerDelegate is correct.

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
```

> Invoked when an existing connection with a peripheral is torn down.

But to receive this notification when your app is in background make sure that you turned on correct background mode - "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" (bluetooth-central).

To turn background mode on select your target -> open "Capabilities" tab -> turn on "Background Modes".

Answer (score 1):

`CBCentralManagerDelegate` has a method called

```
– centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:
```

which is invoked when an existing connection with a peripheral is torn down. I do not know what Apple defines as "torn down", and loosing connectivity due to range issues doesn't necessarily call this method like you would expect it to. Try it out and let me know how things worked out.

Comment: Thanks for response @daniellarsson. I will check and let you know

Comment: The method isn't invoked at all? Try doing a manual disconnect just to make sure you set up your delegate correctly.